# How to make an auto-incrementing id column use missing numbers in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table with 100 rows and an auto-incrementing `id` column, and I delete the row with `id = 15`. How can I add a new row with `id = 15` instead of `id = 101`?

Comment: Don't bother.  Just learn to live with `101` -- or whatever SQL Server decides is best.

Comment: If sequential numbers matter when *viewing* your data, then use `ROW_NUMBER`. The value of the `ID` in a table should be nothing more than a unique identifier; it's actual value is meaningless and gaps in them (if you're using a datatype like an `int`) should both be expected and acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

No, don't do it.

Generated primary keys are used to produce unique values, that are of **internal** use. They are not supposed to "sexy" or nice looking. That is NOT their purpose; the PK purpose is uniqueness. If you are concerned about the specific values, then it means you are **exposing** the PK to the external world... something that raises a lot of red flags.

If you need a value to expose, don't use the PK fot this, but create a secondary column for it. Its solely purpose in the world is to be exposed. This value can have a nice formatting with dashes (like the SSN), prefixes, suffixes, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with an identity key field you could use this:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName ON
INSERT INTO YourTableName (ID, Other) VALUES (15, 'Whatever')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTableName OFF
```

Comment: Better put that in a serializable xact if you don't want side effects

Comment: This *could* cause problems if there is a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on `ID`.

Comment: I hate to see encouragement of bad behavior :-)